# Notification of app download through an ad?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, ads, unityads

I'm using Unity Ads in my game and by using the HandleShowResult function I can see if an ad was finished, skipped or failed. This works well but, is there also a way to find out if the user downloaded the app featured in that particular ad?

```
private void HandleShowResult (ShowResult result)
{
    switch (result)
    {
    case ShowResult.Finished:
        Debug.Log ("Video completed. User rewarded " + rewardQty + " credits.");
        break;
    case ShowResult.Skipped:
        Debug.LogWarning ("Video was skipped.");
        break;
    case ShowResult.Failed:
        Debug.LogError ("Video failed to show.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no experiance in it, but I really doubt there is any way, unless there is some network between featured game owners and unity ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to achieve this, but...

You can play around with OnApplicationFocus right after HandleShowResult. At least you may know your player went to the store.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea, I'll give it a try. Thanks!